# css descendant selector append style excepting of sub elements

Tags: html, css

I have two div which has table . When I apply `css` class table of first div, Then second table of div is affected .

```css
.tbl-generic th:nth-child(-n+2),td:nth-child(-n+2) { 
    background-color:red;
    width:25px;
} 

.tbl-generic th:nth-last-child(-n+3),td:nth-last-child(-n+3) { 
    background-color:red;
    width:25px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="tbl-generic">
    <tr>
    <td style="width:55px;">TEST1</td>
    <td style="width:55px;">TEST2</td>
    <td>TEST3</td>
    <td>TEST4</td>
    <td>TEST5</td>
    <td>TEST6</td>
    <td>TEST7</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>

<div>
 <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:55px;">A</td>
    <td style="width:55px;">B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hv335ha5/)

Comment: Because you also set style on `td`'s in any table `td:nth-child(-n+2)` and `td:nth-last-child(-n+3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `.tbl-generic` in your css

```css
.tbl-generic th:nth-child(-n+2), .tbl-generic td:nth-child(-n+2) { 
    background-color:red;
    width:25px;
} 

.tbl-generic th:nth-last-child(-n+3), .tbl-generic td:nth-last-child(-n+3) { 
    background-color:red;
    width:25px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="tbl-generic">
    <tr>
    <td style="width:55px;">TEST1</td>
    <td style="width:55px;">TEST2</td>
    <td>TEST3</td>
    <td>TEST4</td>
    <td>TEST5</td>
    <td>TEST6</td>
    <td>TEST7</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>

<div>
 <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:55px;">A</td>
    <td style="width:55px;">B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohh Yeah!.This is very simple

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your CSS:

```
.tbl-generic th:nth-child(-n+2),td:nth-child(-n+2) { 

    background-color:red;
    width:25px;
} 

.tbl-generic th:nth-last-child(-n+3),td:nth-last-child(-n+3) { 

    background-color:red;
    width:25px;
}
```

This should be:

```
.tbl-generic th:nth-child(-n+2),
.tbl-generic td:nth-child(-n+2) { 

    background-color:red;
    width:25px;
} 

.tbl-generic th:nth-last-child(-n+3),
.tbl-generic td:nth-last-child(-n+3) { 

    background-color:red;
    width:25px;
}
```

Otherwise, all `td's` would get the styling.

Updated your [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hv335ha5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you are applying css to all `td` not in first div that was the problem
check it

```css
.tbl-generic th:nth-child(-n+2),.tbl-generic td:nth-child(-n+2) { 
    background-color:red;
    width:25px;
} 

.tbl-generic th:nth-last-child(-n+3),.tbl-generic td:nth-last-child(-n+3) { 
    background-color:red;
    width:25px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="tbl-generic">
    <tr>
    <td style="width:55px;">TEST1</td>
    <td style="width:55px;">TEST2</td>
    <td>TEST3</td>
    <td>TEST4</td>
    <td>TEST5</td>
    <td>TEST6</td>
    <td>TEST7</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>

<div>
 <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:55px;">A</td>
    <td style="width:55px;">B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
div:first-of-type .tbl-generic{

}
```